# how do I change the lightbulb in a pendulum lamp?

Tags: lamp

how do I change the lightbulb in a pendulum lamp like this shown in the image? [image]

Answer (score 1):

On the one I had in the past there is a nut at the top, loosen this nut and the globe can now be shifted, holding the globe shift it around moving the nut to the side of the opening. At 1 or 2 positions the edge of the support plate will come out of the globe, now move that to the other side and the fixture will be released. Place the globe on a safe surface hold the fixture and unscrew the lamp and replace. I usually wash the globes with warm soapy water as they usually have dust and grease buildup in and on them and reverse the process to re assemble.

Comment: You can *just* see a grub screw in the left hand side of the collar just above the metal cap.  It looks like it needs an Allen key.  When I have needed to remove the globe, you have needed to slide the cap (+ collar) up the metal rod.